# Нажатие мыши WinAPI, во время перемещение курсора

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Каким образом определить какая из переданных клавиш была нажата используя `WPARAM`.

К примеру определить одну клавишу мыши легко:

```
void window::mouse_move(int x, int y, WPARAM wparam)
{
    if(wparam & WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        wprintf_s(L"left [x: %d, y: %d]\n", x, y);
    if(wparam & WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
        wprintf_s(L"right [x: %d, y: %d]\n", x, y);
}
```

Но в таком случае при зажатии клавиши <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, будет вызван как первое так и второе условие.

Comment: Вы неправильно интерпретируете `WPARAM`. Проверьте [по документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616(v=vs.85).aspx) (не WM_LBUTTONDOWN, а `MK_LBUTTON` и не WM_RBUTTONDOWN, а `MK_RBUTTON`)

Comment: @mega: Запишите как ответ :)

Comment: @mega, хотел бы еще спросить, почему не работают макроопределения `GET_X_LPARAM` и `GET_Y_LPARAM`? Приходится использовать `MAKEPOINTS`

Comment: Создайте новый вопрос с кодом. Без кода вопрос непонятен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616(v=vs.85).aspx), при работе с сообщением `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, нужно использовать специальные макроопределения `MK_RBUTTON`, `MK_LBUTTON`, и т.д.
Большое спасибо @mega.